# Do javascript array's empty elements take up memory?

Tags: javascript, arrays, memory

Usually I convert my data arrays in way that lets me access elements faster later in the code, say the element is an object with an ID property then I set this property as the element's key in the array. To give you an example let's suppose I have this:

`[{id: 1, name: "a"}, {id: 2, name: "b"}, etc..]`

becomes

`[1 => {name: "a"}, 2 => {name: "b"}, etc...]`

then I can simply use `a[2]` without iterating over the array to find the element with `ID = 2`

The problem is some values might be missing which causes empty elements in the array:

```
  1599,
  <2 empty items>,
  1105,
  892,
  <2 empty items>,
  86,
  1695,
  999,
  <1 empty item>,
  967,
  1663,
  <3 empty items>,
  1673,
  <4 empty items>,
  1043,
  998,
  1350,
  1688,
  <3 empty items>,
  2013,
  <2 empty items>,
  136,
  1463,
  1632,
  <1 empty item>,
  1827,
  1680,
  1293,
  <2 empty items>,
  844,
  1696,
  1108,
  <1 empty item>,
  925,
  <6 empty items>,
  1144,
  <7 empty items>,
  905,
  <3 empty items>,
  2006,
  <7 empty items>,
  1876,
  <2 empty items>,
  1609,
  <2 empty items>,
  2232,
  <1 empty item>,
  1561,
  <1 empty item>,
  2203,
  <1 empty item>,
  1400,
  <3 empty items>,
  1381,
  1287,
  1312,
  <2 empty items>,
  933,
  ... 4011 more items ]
```

Are these using memory, should I be concerned?

Comment: They don't. Sparse arrays are not a contiguous memory region - it's just a fancy object. If you have `{a: 1, c:3}` there is no memory reserved for `b`. Same with the (essentially) `{0: "a", 2: "c"}`

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize

Answer (score 5):

Yes they do, And u can easily verify that yourself. 
Create a the following class

```
class EmptyArray {
    constructor(size) {
        this.array = new Array(size)
    }
}
```

Go to any chrome built in chrome page like chrome://version/ (just to have a really simple static page), open dev tools and choose allocation instrumentation on timeline option (without stack recordings) , start recording then create 3 instances

```
a = new EmptyArray(1)
a = new EmptyArray(90)
a = new EmptyArray(90000)
```

Stop the recording and then check the retained size of these 3 instances, you will see that they are extremely different in size

here is a screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sparse arrays are just messy use the [cleaner array methods](https://lorenstewart.me/2017/01/22/javascript-array-methods-mutating-vs-non-mutating/). Use [`.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) and it'll return an array of arrays. Each sub-array is a key/value pair (an entry). In this case the keys are index numbers since it's a real array:

```
let arrayofArrays = objectArray.entries();

// [[0, {object}], [1, {object}], [2, {object}],...]
```

Compact the array using [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter):

```
objectArray.filter(obj => obj !== undefined && obj != null && obj !== '');
```

Then take that array of arrays and convert it into a [Map](https://hackernoon.com/what-you-should-know-about-es6-maps-dc66af6b9a1e) for easy access:

```
let arrayMap = new Map(arrayOfArrays);

arrayMap.get(2);

// returns the 3rd Object
```

#### Demo

```js
let objArray = [{id: 1, name: "a"}, {id: 2, name: "b"}, null, {id: 1, name: "c"}];

let cleanObjArray = compactArray(objArray);

let arrayMap = new Map(cleanObjArray.entries());
// [[0, {id: 1, name: "a"}], [1, {id: 2, name: "b"}], [2, {id: 1, name: "c"}];

console.log(arrayMap.get(2));

function compactArray(array) {
  return array.filter(obj => obj !== undefined && obj != null && obj !== '');
}
```

Comment: thanks, this is really nice but I have a feeling that for larger arrays my messy approach is a bit faster, in my case speed matters if it doesn't come with a significant memory usage, hence my question

Comment: Your data must be in the kifillions, although modern browsers are quite impressive lately.